# How to start ordered list from 2 not 1 with w3c validity and IE 6 compatibility?

Tags: css

How to start ordered list from 2 not 1?

with all browser compatibility including IE6 and html css should bevalid

Comment: Do you need to do this in CSS or can you change the HTML?

Comment: @musicfreak - if it's not possible through css then will go to chsnge html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see is to put the first `LI` in but hide it using css

Comment: @adam - +1 for nice idea. Although it's not semantically correct and against to accessibility

Comment: It is semantically correct and can be accessibility, depending on how you are going to use it.

Comment: Don't make it empty. There must be a first item in the list, even if you are starting at #2. Put that first item in, then hide it. Like I said, accessibility depends on how you'll use it in your context

Comment: but what we will put in empty li?

Comment: It might help if we knew the context

Answer (score 9):

this can be done directly via html with the `start` attribute

```
<ol start="2">
  <li>item two</li>
  <li>item three</li>
</ol>
```

it's [not possible](http://www.highdots.com/forums/cascading-style-sheets/using-css-set-start-number-262555.html) with only css, and it seems like IE doesn't support the `start` attribute …

Comment: @knittl - I checked on IE 8 and FF 3.5 it's working, just checked in IE 7 it's working

Comment: You can also use `<li value="2">` for the first item, and all following items will continue from that number. The attribute is deprecated but I would still use it considering they haven't created any other alternative to it (how can you deprecate something without providing an alternative?).

Comment: @knittl - but it's being validated `<ol start="2">`

Comment: @animuson - it also doesn't validate `<li value="2">`

Comment: @knittl - see my above comments

Comment: Use Transitional DOCTYPE, `start`/`value` will validate. There is still some controversy over whether they should have been deprecated. They are back in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

To start at 3.1 put two blanks at the start and hide them.

```
<li style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute;">&nbsp;</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this:

http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/make-ol-list-start-from-number-different-than-1-using-css.html

EDIT: Strike that. Doesn't work in IE6. Sorry.